# How to install Unity 2017.2 Beta 9 in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, command-line, unity, android

I want to develop a Augment Reality android App. Can anyone help me to how to setup the platform in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Mostly in all sites they are giving help for windows and mac OS

Comment: For developing Android apps you need the Android SDK / Android Studio or something similar.

Comment: I want to develop augment reality app for that i want unity 2017.2 also.

Comment: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/ (just needs some googling)

Comment: that's not working properly

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask Please understand that vague statements like "didn't work" are meaningless. Now, you either use the link above and post your case there (preferably) or here you must [edit] your question and describe what you did, what was expected to happen and what happened instead.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation of how to install Unity is kept up to date in this thread:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/

The last post on the thread contains the how-to